# macro use in array initialization

Tags: macros

I'm pretty confused by this bit of code in a microchip demo application for a PIC24F microcontroller. It looks like this macro is being assigned at runtime to the address of this array. I didn't think that was possible, so my limited knowledge of c is really failing me right now. Would anyone be able to provide some insight?

```
#define MBR_ADDR_TAG
#define MBR_ATTRIBUTES __attribute__((space(psv), address(DRV_FILEIO_INTERNAL_FLASH_CONFIG_FILES_ADDRESS)))

...

const uint8_t MBR_ATTRIBUTES MasterBootRecord[FILEIO_CONFIG_MEDIA_SECTOR_SIZE] MBR_ADDR_TAG =
{....}
```

Comment: "this macro is being assigned at runtime to the address of this array" - what macro??? Whatever is assigned to the array is shown as `...` in the code that you provided. Whether it's a preprocessor definition (aka *macro*), or "plain" values, it is completely possible, but if you claim that it is not, then please provide whatever is written between those curly braces.

Comment: what's confusing me is that MBR_ADDR_TAG is in a #define statement, and then is used in the initialization of MasterBootRecord[], where MBR_ADDR_TAG = {...}. What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

upon reading my own question from a few years ago i see the answer now. MBR_ADDR_TAG is just inserted into the declaration/initialization of MasterBootRecord[], but because it was never defined as anything it is just ignored, so it is equivalent to:

```
#define MBR_ATTRIBUTES __attribute__((space(psv), address(DRV_FILEIO_INTERNAL_FLASH_CONFIG_FILES_ADDRESS)))

...

const uint8_t MBR_ATTRIBUTES MasterBootRecord[FILEIO_CONFIG_MEDIA_SECTOR_SIZE] =
{....}
```